# Visual Studio 2013 will not debug with Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-studio-2013, internet-explorer-11

Internet Explorer 11 no longer debugs or starts without debugging on any project or page launched from Visual Studio 2013. Firefox and Chrome debug and run just fine, so I am quite certain that the problem is in IE and wish I could uninstall or "repair" it but see no way to do that.

I have reset IE to default settings and repeatedly erased browser history, etc. If anything that has made the problem worse;  there is now no indication that IE is doing anything (no "waiting for localhost" or spinner) for perhaps 5 minutes, at which point, a little error message comes up at the bottom of the browser saying that web page is not responding and offering to recover webpage. When I select recovery, it closes the browser and shows this error message:

```
 Description:
  A problem caused this program to stop interacting with Windows.

  Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   AppHangXProcB1
  Application Name: iexplore.exe
  Application Version:  11.0.9600.17909
```

....

I'd be very grateful for any help in fixing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem, at least temporarily, by going to Windows Control Panel, choosing the Turn Windows Features On and Off option on the left, and turning off IE.

That action closed the features dialog, so I reopened it and "turned on" IE. That seems to have cleared it in a way that resetting did not do.

I also tried again to Google for suggestions and, after scrolling past the dubious magic repair apps, see [this Windows page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie-crashes-stops-working#ie=ie-11), which suggests turning IE on and off, plus some other suggestions.